# how login works?

Tags: authentication

Well, you type username and password in form, hit "OK" button. Then data going to server side and check users database if that user is existed. Then it return user id. And what next?
That data is saved in cookies?
Does it mean, that with every clicked link, site login you to website again?

I mean,

1. you click some link on site
2. browser redirect you to that page
3. site checks your cookies
4. site grab username and password from cookies
5. site checks is that data is valid (via connecting to database)
6. show page to you

Is that correct?

Comment: Not every webpage and/or web-server works the same way, so it is impossible to answer your question without knowing what site you are talking about.

Answer (score 10):

1. User enters credential.
2. System validates credential.
3. Upon successful authentication, server saves user object into session.
4. System grabs user info from session.
5. System displays webpage.

Tadaa!! :)

**UPDATE**

To add a little more...

1. User visits the secured webpage.
2. System checks if session contains a user object.
3. If user object exists in session, allow user through to visit the page.
4. If user object doesn't exists, redirect user to login page.

You don't need to store user password in the session. In fact, it is highly discouraged. Checking to make sure the user object exists in the session is sufficient.

When the user clicks the logout page, then proceed to invalidate the session... that's it. :)

Comment: what exactly should i store in session?

Comment: The session should contain the user object (username, first namel mast name, all the pertinent information you need). This way, when you need to personalize your website, you can display "Hello Mike", by pulling the first name from the session. Putting user information in session the most straightforward, you don't need to worry about user disabling cookies. Further, if you use session, when user closes the browser, it will automatically kill the session whereas if you use cookies, you probably need to perform further checks.

Answer (score 4):

Almost correct. You rarely go to the database with every request. You usually set a cookie with a expiry date and save the user session and info in memory. So every time a request is made, if the user is not authenticated, you authenticate him, generate and send him a cookie with, say, 5h expiry. So, in the next 5 hours, whenever a request comes in with that cookie, you trust that the user is an authenticated, valid user and you don't have to check the database.

It's not how every site does it nor it is the only way to manage session and cookies but I think it is the most widely used.

Comment: but what exactly i should store in cookies? Username and decrypt password? But how can i trust this data, without checking users database?

Comment: Why would you need his password between requests? You should only store the info you need about the user to display the pages. Usually that is username, user id, some profile info, etc... Unless you are using ssl communication you can never trust 100% that the data is correct. Someone can "sniff" the connection and steal the user cookie (which is known as session hijacking). If it makes you feel safer, even facebook travels unencrypted cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use sessions, but that's pretty much the gist of it.  That way the data doesn't accidentally persist.

I mean, for my simple site at home, that's how I do it.  But it's still locally hosted, so the security is guaranteed to be crap.

Oh, and no need to check with the database whenever you click on another link -- too much time wasted.

Comment: Why sessions but not cookies? Cookies have expiration date, and not deletes every time you close browser

Comment: Cookies can be spoofed.  This problem can be overcome, but it requires more work.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an application takes advantage of the session that is established between the browser and the web server, and makes a note that that session is "authenticated". "session" is a built in feature of HTTP.  If the browser is closed, or after a certain period of time passes, the session is automatically closed.  If the user does an explicit logout, the application marks the session as not-authenticated.